# Is there shorthand syntax for creating conditional NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Is there a way how to create conditional NSDictionary? For example, lets assume there's a custom class with 3 properties:

```
class UserInfoObject
   firstName
   lastName
   address
```

What I need is to create NSDictionary for non-nil properties out of userInfoObject. It straightforward when I know what properties are non-nil in advance, so I could use this shorthand syntax (or classic one):

```
NSDictionary *userInfoDic = @{@"firstName": userInfoObject.firstName, @"lastName":userInfoObject.lastName, @"address":userInfoObject.address}
```

However in my case, I need to create mutable dictionary and then perform manual check/add for each of the property. Is there another shorter way for doing below?

```
// Create mutable thing
NSMutableDictionary *userInfoDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];

// Check and add first name
if (userInfoDic.firstName) {
   userInfoDic[@"firstName"] = userInfoDic.firstName;
}

// Check and add last name 
if (userInfoDic.lastName) {
   userInfoDic[@"lastName"] = userInfoDic.lastName;
}

// Check and add address
if (userInfoDic.address) {
   userInfoDic[@"address"] = userInfoDic.address;
}
```

I had pretty much classes and properties, so shorthand (if exists) could facilitate the process :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSMutableDictionary already does this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000141-BAJJCBIE).

`setValue:forKey:` does this for a mutable dictionary:

> This method adds value and key to the dictionary using `setObject:forKey:`, unless value is nil in which case the method instead attempts to remove key using `removeObjectForKey:`.

So, use `setValue:forKey:` instead of `setObject:forKey:`. There is no shorthand literal for this method. You could write your own NSMutableDictionary subclass and override `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` to safely ignore `nil` objects, but it seems like too much work. As the documents say:

> There should typically be little need to subclass NSMutableDictionary. If you do need to customize behavior, it is often better to consider composition rather than subclassing.

Take this to mean that you should, rather than subclass, create your own wrapper object that has an NSMutableDictionary as a backing store, and implements all the required methods to access the inner dictionary, overriding `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` to work with nil. But I wouldn't recommend it just to avoid a few lines of code elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a shorthand syntax for setValue:forKey:? Because I assume  this one (userInfoObject[@"firstName"] = @"John") uses  "setObject:forKey:"

Comment: It actually uses setObject:forKeyedSubscript: as explained here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html there is no shorthand for setValue:forKey: